# Numba synonym for adding values using boolean indexing in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to create more efficient code but am stuck on implementing a Numba version of the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0]])

bool_idx = np.array([True, False, False, True])

a[0, bool_idx] += 3
a

array([[3, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Unfortunately I get an error when porting this code to a function with numba:

```
@njit
def add_to_arr(a, idx, arr_bool, add):
    arr[idx, arr_bool] += 3
    return arr

add_to_arr(a=a, idx=0, arr_bool=bool_idx, add=3)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function getitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(int32, 2d, C), (int64, array(bool, 1d, C)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Numba only allows advanced indexing in this case on the first dimension of an array. We can rewrite the function (also correcting a mild typo) to accommodate this, just using a transpose and reversing the index:

```
@njit 
def add_to_arr(a, idx, arr_bool, add): 
    a.T[arr_bool, idx] += 3 
    return a 

add_to_arr(a, 0, bool_idx, 3)
```

This works for me, giving:

```
array([[3, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#array-access) says that advanced indexing is only allowed in one dimension but doesn't specify that this needs to be the first dimension, so this might be a bug.